# Solution to disable default select option open behavior on "NEXT" virtual button of iOS keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I have developed hybrid application with Cordova (PhoneGap/ HTML / jQuery/ CSS) on iOS platoform and I am facing application crash issue on one scenario.

In the page I have mentioned three select elements in a sequence along with few inputs. When I focus on first input element of form and used "NEXT" button of virtual keyboard to move next element it work fine till it come to first select option. Once first select option get focus by "NEXT" button event it open up its option window. if I do not wait on first select option and press "NEXT" button then my application get crashed. I have tried multiple option to fixed this issue like below:

1) keeping all options disable till user click on its parent div. but event does not work on disable select option. However it work on other area like its associated label.
2) keeping hidden input next to select option with tabindex=1

I searched lot but didn't find any proper solution. Searched to disable NEXT button focus event on select option to remove default behavior of select option on iOS.

Does anyone have idea to fix this issue? Do we have any safari/iOS base attribute to disable default behavior OR any jquery/ javascript solution?

Best Regards,
Jeet

Comment: I have tried "size" attribute to select option as per details below given on developer.apple.com site but it didn't work. On the website they have mentioned as below

"Discussion
The select element specifies a selection menu. This block must contain a set of option elements or optgroup elements containing options. In Safari, if the size property is explicitly set for this element, the input box resembles a Mac OS X combo box, otherwise it resembles a pop-up menu."  

On iPhone it consider <select> tag as picker which come to keyboard place but on iPad it open as pop-up menu.

Comment: Is it possible to open <select><option> as combo box as iPhone on iPad? Anyone have any solution for it?